# Wifi Card / Mobile Hot Spot

Tags: applications, wi-fi, mobile-network, android-studio

I am learning about networking, specifically the data link to session layers. I have an extra android phone I have been learning with on various things, and I am at the point where the application framework layer is simply using other references to really 'do the work' of listening and handling wifi data. I am willing to code with android studio's NDK, or even use the uncompiled kernal code. However, I just need to know where should I look to see the inner workings of how android receives and handles wifi data?

I think what I would like to do as a test project is set up a 'mobile hot spot' that grabs wifi data and sends it to my router. Any help would be appreciated; thanks!

Comment: Hi, while we probably could help to answer the technical matter, take note that development questions are off-topic since Android Enthusiasts focuses on end-users or power-users (but not necessarily developers) solving their issues.